# How to count a word having an apostrophe as two separate words using Java regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which is having a word with an apostrophe.
Ex- He is a very very good boy, isn't he?

```
public class Solution {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

           String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
           String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
           int itemCount = words.length;
           System.out.println(itemCount);

           for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                String word = words[i];
                System.out.println(word);
           }
     }
}
```

Output I'm getting is 9 words. But I want the count as 10, by separating isn't as 2 words. How to do it using the above Regular Expression?

Comment: use alternation :- `String[] words = s.split("\\s+|'");`

Comment: Hat tip to the above comment, but are you sure you want `isn't` to become `isn` and `t`?

Comment: @rock321987 Ok. How do I specify comma( , ) Question mark ( ? ) etc. if I declare them with | , it is counting as a word and word count is getting increased.

Comment: @Protagonist can you elaborate a bit? Provide some example

Comment: @rock321987 In the above string "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?" the word count should be 10 and I want to omit comma and question mark. Like this - He is a very very good boy isn t he

Comment: @Protagonist i think you need **[`\w`](http://ideone.com/fsO1dH)**

Comment: @rock321987 I tried with \w but it is giving me word count 11 (comma as a  separate word)

Comment: @Protagonist don't use split..please see the demo..

Answer (score 1):

It would be more reliable to use the `\w` construct:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("He is a very very good boy, isn't he?");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Otherwise, you need to handle too many situations manually, for instance: "He's a very good boy.Isn't he?".

Comment: How do I count the number of words then? In the above example string the count should be 10

Comment: `Matcher` is lazy (for performance reasons). It doesn't find all the matches before you ask it to. So, the only way to find the count of matches is to iterate through them and count them manually. If you need to print the count before the words, just collect the words into a list while counting, and then print the list. If you need this logic frequently, just create a wrapper around `Matcher` with this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `isn't` to be `is not` and so count them as 2 separate words and not single one.

You can have *or* (`|`) in split regular expression,

```
\\s+|'t
```

This will only for `'t` and it will avoid to count for sentence like `my friend's birthday..` here apostrophe should not be considered for another word.

But that's not just an end of the story. There are lot of other contractions are there which should be consider in such expression.

*i.e.*

- **'t**  : isn't, aren't, wasn't, weren't, wouldn't, didn't etc.
- **'s**  : it's, that's, etc. (This is difficult one)
- **'d**  : I'd, you'd etc.
- **'ll** : I'll, they'll etc.
  ...

So ultimately following regular expression will solve 90% of the problem counting word.

```
\\s+|'t|'d|'ll
```

Problem with `'s`(apostrophe S) is it comes with subject like Dog's, Cat's etc. which shows possession and these should not be considered as two separate words. On the other end some time we use `'s` to write It is, That is(*That's, It's*) etc. You can add the expressions in existing regular expression to differentiate between contractions and apostrophe which shows possession.

Note : This is only for counting the words and it will split `isn't` as `isn` and (*space*), `'t` will be removed.

Comment: OK. How do I omit ! ? etc in the sentence by use of or ( | ) in the same expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using p{Punct}, which ignores characters like ?!

```
        String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
        String[] words = s.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
        int itemCount = words.length;
        System.out.println(itemCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            String word = words[i];
            System.out.println(word);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on non-word chars:

```
String[] words = s.split("\\W+")
```

Comment: I want a count too

Comment: @Protagonist `int count = words.length;`